# Composite function with integral

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Suppose $f(z)=\int_{0}^{z} g(y)dy, h(x)=x^2$, then the composite $f\circ h=\int_{0}^{x^2} g(y)dy$. Is this correct?

Comment: Since $\color{blue}{h(x)}=\color{blue}{x^2}$,

$$(f\circ h)(x)=f(\color{blue}{h(x)})=\int_{0}^{\color{blue}{h(x)}} g(y)dy=\int_{0}^{\color{blue}{x^2}} g(y)dy.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's right. $f \circ h = f(h(x))$ so you just plug in $h(x)$ for $z$ to get $\int_{0}^{x^2} g(y) dy$.

Comment: It should be $f\circ h(x)$

Comment: $(f \circ h)(x) = f(h(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct because $$f(h(x))=f(x^2)=\int_{0}^{x^2} g(y) dy. $$